# CUPS fails to start due to dependency on Ubuntu 20.04.2 Server

Tags: server, 20.04, printing, dependencies

Trying to install `cups` on Ubuntu 20.04.2 Server, so that I can use it as a print server.

Installation via:

```
sudo apt install cups
```

appears to succeed.

```
sudo systemctl start cups
```

executes without producing an error message. But I cannot access the web interface at `localhost:631`, and:

```
sudo systemctl status cups
```

returns:

```
● cups.service - CUPS Scheduler
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/cups.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: inactive (dead) (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2021-05-28 22:07:21 UTC; 1min 38s ago
TriggeredBy: ● cups.path
             ● cups.socket
       Docs: man:cupsd(8)
   Main PID: 2340 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

May 28 22:07:21 computer systemd[1]: cups.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 30.
May 28 22:07:21 computer systemd[1]: Stopped CUPS Scheduler.
May 28 22:07:21 computer systemd[1]: Dependency failed for CUPS Scheduler.
May 28 22:07:21 computer systemd[1]: cups.service: Job cups.service/start failed with result 'dependency'.
```

Google has not produced any useful information. What do I need to do to fix this (command line only)?

Comment: Look at the `/lib/systemd/system/cups.service` file, and replicate the command in your terminal. You may see more messages. Read `man cupsd`.

Comment: Thanks. That did it.

Answer (score 2):

The culprit was a badly formatted netmask in /etc/cups/cupsd.conf. I gather this was causing cups.socket to fail, which was the "dependency failed" above.

The step to identifying this was to run "sudo cupsd -t", which tests the cupsd.conf syntax.